# `kusama-staging` v0.9.37 runtime finalizing, (apparently) validating and backing, but not including new parablocks

Tags: test-network

The following problem seems to be pretty deep in the bowels of the para backing process and a quick substrate code study didn't get me there, so i'm looking for help on

- a) what could have gone wrong here, and more importantly
- b) is this state recoverable somehow?

**Situation:**

We have a (semi-persistent, networked) `calamari` parachain testnet deployment with a `kusama-staging` relaychain (15 validators / 3 parachains) and noticed over the weekend that the attached 3 parachains all simultaneously stopped producing blocks (they were previously doing so just fine for 4 days).

Around that time, the following Relaychain logs started appearing in the relay validators and the internal relay nodes of the para clients.
`Could not retrieve session info from rolling session window session=364`

The relay continues to build and finalize blocks as normal, and the para clients stay in sync with it. They also continue peering with each other, produce block candidates and send them to validators for backing, they seem to validate them just fine, but they never become new best blocks.

Currently `session.currentIndex: u32 => 427` on the relay (note block candidates are produced for 364)
Relay logs contain large amounts of `Timeout hit - already seconded?` traces but I can't judge whether that's normal or suspicious.

Longform log of one relayblock with backing debug info on one of the validators: https://pastebin.com/xiHw75wG

**Attempts:**

- shutdown all collators except for one, `calamari revert 999` to evict all current block proposals, restart collation. Error stays the same with session 364
- shutdown all collators, resync a collator from scratch from an archive node, start collation. same error.